# Pandas create categorical column filled in with string values from other variable

Tags: pandas

I have multiple files with foreign key relations (in csv). So one file will refer to a page as number 123, and there is a separate file that maps that number to '/homepage'. The mapping file is not ordereded and not zero based.

I can't figure out from the documentation how to use `astype('category`) with a lookup dict or something.

Any help?

```
# the file with the foreign keys
lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({'page':[123,2,3], 'name':['/homepage','/search','/checkout']})
# the file with the pages
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'pages':[2,3,123]})

# wanted df1, with categorical 'pages' column
#   pages
# 0 /search
# 1 /checkout
# 2 /homepage

# but instead ofcourse
#    pages
# 0      2
# 1      3
# 2    123
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
from functools import cache

import pandas as pd

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"page": [123, 2, 3], "name": ["/homepage", "/search", "/checkout"]}
)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"pages": [2, 3, 123, 4, 3, 123, 2]})


@cache
def match(value):
    try:
        return lookup_df.loc[lookup_df["page"] == value, "name"].values[0]
    except IndexError:
        return "/unknown"


df1["name"] = df1["pages"].apply(match)

print(df1)
# Output
   pages       name
0      2    /search
1      3  /checkout
2    123  /homepage
3      4   /unknown
4      3  /checkout
5    123  /homepage
6      2    /search
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking along! That would work but would be rather inefficient. I'm dealing with quite big files.

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer with a more efficient solution (caching results), although it might not be enough in your case. Cheers.